# multiDatesPicker: how to disable clicking without changing date button color?

Tags: datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I downloaded multiDatesPicker here:
http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net

My Problem is..

I'm using multiDatesPicker only for represent added dates by codes.

And I don't want to receive any user interaction.

The only thing that how to disabling multiDatesPicker I know is "disabled: true" option.
but this makes the calendar's added dates button color changed.

I already tried changing opacity using css(.ui-state-disabled) but it was just opacity.

Is there anyone who know how to just disabling calendar without changing anything that we can see ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

self answer

this solution is work in both datepicker and multidatespicker. just follow 2 steps

**First, change javascript**

in your "jquery.ui.datepicker.js" source codes, find below

```
(unselectable ? '<span class="ui-state-default">' + printDate.getDate() + '</span>' : 
                         '<a class="ui-state-default' + ..
```

and change this to:

```
(/*(unselectable ? '<span class="ui-state-default">' + printDate.getDate() + '</span>' : 
                         */'<a class="ui-state-default' +
```

**Second, add css style**

```
#yourCal .ui-state-disabled {
    BACKGROUND-IMAGE: none; FILTER: none; opacity: .99;
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-state-highlight a {
    background: #743620 none;
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add this one more option to your datepicker initialization code, it worked

```
 onSelect:function (dateText, inst) {
    var newDate = new Date();
    inst.drawMonth = newDate.getMonth();
    inst.drawYear = newDate.getFullYear();
    inst.currentMonth = newDate.getMonth();
    inst.currentYear = newDate.getFullYear();
}
```