# Datepicker change selectable date color CSS

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I have a date picker that has colors of days set dynamically. The only dates selectable are set to ALL Sundays only. My color pattern is set to every third day - the un-selectable dates are a muted red, the selectable dates are a bright red. - I want the selectable dates to be muted like the others.

CSS on selectable cell looks like: `class    ui-datepicker-week-end shiftColor_C ui-datepicker-current-day`

CSS on unelectable cell looks like: `class   ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled red_day_off`

I have setup: http://jsfiddle.net/jeffbarclay/hnjv3L8e/1/ of working copy!

[image]

CODE:

```
var array = ["8/19/2014","11/19/2014","08/25/2014"]

function noKelly(pick) {
  var kelly = 4;
  var dow = pick.getDay();
    if(dow==kelly) return [false,''];
    return [true,''];  
}

function noWeekEnds(pick) {
var dow = pick.getDay();
if (dow > 5 || dow < 1) return [false, ''];
return [true, ''];
}

function onlySunday(pick) {
var dow = pick.getDay();
if (dow > 0) return [false, ''];
return [true, ''];
}

function myAssignedLeave(pick) {
    var string = $.datepicker.formatDate('m/d/yy', pick);
    return [ array.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
}

function unavailable(pick) {
var utcPick = new Date(pick.getUTCFullYear(), pick.getUTCMonth(), pick.getUTCDate(), 0, 0, 0);
//-- converts your pick to utc time
var utcStart = new Date(2014, 0, 0).getTime(); //gets utc time
var day = Math.round((utcPick - utcStart) / 86400);
var nwe = noWeekEnds(pick);
var nkd = noKelly(pick);
var assLeave = myAssignedLeave(pick);
var osun = onlySunday(pick);
var Rnd1 = (true) && osun[0];   // First Round full weeks

var myShift = "B";

var Ashift = (day%3===0) && nkd[0] && assLeave[0];  // A Shift
var Bshift = (day%3===1) && nkd[0] && assLeave[0];  // B Shift
var Cshift = (day%3===2) && nkd[0] && assLeave[0];  // C Shift
var Dshift = (true) && nwe[0] && assLeave[0];  // D Shift

var Shift = "";
var ShiftColor = "";
var ShiftColorDayOff = "false";
var DO_ShiftColor = "";

if(myShift=="A") (Shift = Ashift) &&  (ShiftColor = "shiftColor_A");
if(myShift=="B") (Shift = Bshift) &&  (ShiftColor = "shiftColor_B");
if(myShift=="C") (Shift = Cshift) &&  (ShiftColor = "shiftColor_C"); 
if(myShift=="D") (Shift = Dshift) &&  (ShiftColor = "shiftColor_D"); 


//var shift = (true) && osun[0];
Shift = Rnd1;

if((day%3===1) && (osun[0] === false)) return [ false, 'green_day_off', 'unavailable' ];

return [Shift, ShiftColor, "Unavailable"];  
}

$(document).ready(function () {
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: unavailable
});

$('#datepicker').attr('readonly', true);
});
```

Comment: `if((day%3===1) && (osun[0] === false)) return [ false, 'green_day_off', 'unavailable' ];`
You're adding the unavailable property to days here, but you're restricting it to days that aren't sunday?

Comment: correct, I only want the Sundays selectable - just need the color on Sundays to be muted...

Comment: so why not have another one that's something along the lines of:
day%3 === 1 and isSunday then return muted? Are you just not sure where the muted property is getting added? That's just a jquery ui class.

Comment: I'm not sure how to make it muted? - look at my CSS in the fiddle, selectable is an anchor and unelectable is `<TD>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found two ways to approach this:

1) change to opacity of the selectable cell to .35 in the style

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar .shiftColor_C a {
  color: white;
  background: red;
  border-color: black;
  padding:3px; 
  opacity: .35;
}
```

2) increase the opacity in the un-selectable cells to .99 in style

```
.ui-datepicker .ui-state-disabled {
  opacity: .99;
}
```

both approaches will give a consistent look.

Example in: http://jsfiddle.net/jeffbarclay/hnjv3L8e/5/

Helpful link in SO: [multiDatesPicker: how to disable clicking without changing date button color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318505/multidatespicker-how-to-disable-clicking-without-changing-date-button-color?s=5|1.9769)

[image]